# How can I update Kittens game without losing my village?

Tags: kittens-game

I've been playing Kittens game for a while now, and I noticed that I am a few version behind the times (I'm on 0.9.6.9 according to the top right corner).

How can I update to the latest version without losing my progress? I pressed "Save" but that didn't have any visible effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's all you need to do.  Click the save button, then refresh the page.  As long as you have javascript enabled (I didn't, and gave myself a heart attack when I refreshed), it'll find your save game, and you're off to the races.

Comment: Thanks! I trusted my kittens to you, and they have returned safely from the refresh.

Comment: export first for paranoias' sake?  Or maybe for super paranoid, save all the pages and javascript too?

Answer (score 9):

The safest way to protect your kittens is to export your save file using the Options tab in the top right.  Save first, then export that save into a text file (or just copy it to your clipboard), then refresh.  If something should happen and your save not load correctly after the refresh, you can import your text-save instead of starting over.  I export daily, just in case.